# Unable to generate sitemap.xml in Magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, aws, sitemaps

Recently i moved from Cpanel to AWS afer that when i click on generate sitemap i am getting below error.

Path "/var/www/html/" cannot be used with directory "/var/www/html/"

For reference please find the attached image.
[image]

Comment: are you using the 'pub' location as root for your project?

Comment: @Diana Botean I put all files in HTML folder

Comment: maybe it's not writeable? try adding the sitemap to a different directory and regenerate it

Comment: @Diana Botean It was resolved by changing HTML folder permission from 755 to 775

Answer (score 0):

It was resolved by changing HTML folder permission from 755 to 775

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you change back the permissions and serve the requests from the *'pub'* folder and not leave the project root folder permissions to 775. it's too permissive.

please check the [Magento official documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/tutorials/change-docroot-to-pub.html) on how and why to serve the application from the pub folder. your sitemap will be generated in that folder and you can keep the same sitemap settings.

Comment: I will do what you had suggested

Comment: great! after you switch to the new configuration, please let me know if you still encounter the original problem with the sitemap. in my opinion, your problem should be gone (and your website safer) :)